# How to build HTML content with click function in typescript file and pass it to HTML page

Tags: typescript, angular7

```
    `<button (click)="reloadPage()">Click Here To Refresh</button>`
```

I have to build this html content in typescript and pass it to HTML.  And onClick of button, reloadPage() function defined in typescript file should be executed.

Comment: You need to build a Single Page Application or use a templating engine

Comment: Yes I'm using single page application. Can u share more details on templating engine @Tobin